# Exiting early due to double fault - VS for MAC - MAUI application

Tags: xcode, macos, maui

I am getting below error when I run my MAUI application on the VS for MAC.

```
2023-11-07 07:49:40.986207-0600 MyAppName[6101:58771] warning: Could not load signature of Xamarin.HotReload.Loader:CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000036 from typeref (expected class 'System.ResolveEventArgs' in assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51') assembly:netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 type:System.ResolveEventArgs member:(null)

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x115af5774 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x115a99a8e - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x1159f051f - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x7ff836167dfd - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x0 - Unknown
    0x115b2320f - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : generate_code
    0x115b26768 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : generate
    0x115b261d6 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_interp_transform_method
    0x115b06dd2 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_transform_method
    0x115af9960 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_exec_method
    0x115af6e03 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x11591db9d - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_try_invoke
    0x1145df2e3 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : mono_do_invoke_method
    0x1145db89d - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : suspend_current
    0x1145de3ee - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : process_event
    0x1145ddbe4 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : mono_dbg_process_breakpoint_events
    0x1145f2d92 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : mono_de_process_breakpoint
    0x1145e9adf - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : debugger_agent_breakpoint_from_context
    0x14412c07f - Unknown
    0x115b066f5 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_debugger_tramp
    0x115b03d90 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_exec_method
    0x115af6e03 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x11591c0e8 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x1159240fc - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_exec_main_checked
    0x115a52ce2 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_exec
    0x114a18c77 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib : xamarin_main
    0x10efedcf4 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/MyAppName : main
    0x10f50a2bf - Unknown
    0x113a4d52e - Unknown

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x115af5dab):0x115af5d9b  be d0 00 00 00 e8 bb 43 e6 ff 49 89 c4 4c 89 38  .......C..I..L.8
0x115af5dab  41 0f b7 46 08 41 89 84 24 a0 00 00 00 41 8b 46  A..F.A..$....A.F
0x115af5dbb  0c c1 e8 16 83 e0 01 41 89 84 24 a4 00 00 00 b8  .......A..$.....
0x115af5dcb  00 00 3f 00 41 23 46 0c 3d 00 00 05 00 0f 94 c0  ..?.A#F.=.......

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void__this___string_string <0x0009c>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at MyAppName.Program:Main <0x00004>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00108>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

An error has occurred in the native fault reporting. Some diagnostic information will be unavailable.

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x115af5774 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x115a99a8e - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x1159f051f - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x7ff836167dfd - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x0 - Unknown
    0x115b2320f - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : generate_code
    0x115b26768 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : generate
    0x115b261d6 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_interp_transform_method
    0x115b06dd2 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_transform_method
    0x115af9960 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_exec_method
    0x115af6e03 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x11591db9d - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_try_invoke
    0x1145df2e3 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : mono_do_invoke_method
    0x1145db89d - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : suspend_current
    0x1145de3ee - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : process_event
    0x1145ddbe4 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : mono_dbg_process_breakpoint_events
    0x1145f2d92 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : mono_de_process_breakpoint
    0x1145e9adf - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmono-component-debugger.dylib : debugger_agent_breakpoint_from_context
    0x14412c07f - Unknown
    0x115b066f5 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_debugger_tramp
    0x115b03d90 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_exec_method
    0x115af6e03 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x11591c0e8 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x1159240fc - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_exec_main_checked
    0x115a52ce2 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_exec
    0x114a18c77 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib : xamarin_main
    0x10efedcf4 - /Users/companyname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD71E2DB-E71F-4D50-BEA8-B20CEE381BC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3B73FD2D-C12C-476D-B4BC-1847BE762D72/MyAppName.app/MyAppName : main
    0x10f50a2bf - Unknown
    0x113a4d52e - Unknown

Exiting early due to double fault
```

**My VS Details:**

**Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac**

**Version 17.6.6 (build 408)**

**My Xcode Version: 14.2 (14C18)**

I can't install the latest **Xcode 15.0.1** since MAC system not supporting it. Is that the reason for this issue? Do I need to install the VS code for solving this issue?

Comment: Try to use VSCODE to see if there is any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the hot reload option from `Visual Studio > Preferences > Tools for Xamarin > XAML Hot Reload` and try rerunning the application.

May be you are facing these issue, due to the `Xcode` lower version.